# Fragment (ScrollView) Covering Bottom NavView Items

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments, android-scrollview

I have a Fragment with a ScrollView and a BottomNavBar from which the Fragment is inflated but when compiled the ScrollView cover the Bottom Nav Bar making is unusable how do I restrict the content of the Fragment to only the rest of the screen leaving the bottom navbar as it is.

BottomNav Bar Activity Code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/landing_page_body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".pages.LandingPage"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        >

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:transformPivotX="100dp"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navbar_menu"

            app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"/>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/side_navbar_header"
        app:menu="@menu/side_navbar_menu" />


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Fragment xml Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:isScrollContainer="false">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".fragments.auction_add">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="Enter Auction Details -"
            android:textSize="40dp"></TextView>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"></ImageView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp">


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Name of Item"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp">


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Description"
                android:maxLength="40"
                android:maxLines="5"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls"
                android:padding="5dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp">


            <EditText
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"

                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Initial Price"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/startTimePicker"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Start Time"
                android:maxLines="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/endTimePicker"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="End Time"
                android:maxLines="1" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginVertical="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingVertical="5dp">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
                android:text="Post Item" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Output -
[Final Result of Above XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp0g9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this below code in the bottom of parent linearlayout in Fragment xml Code

```
 <View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp">

</View>
```

Hope it will work...